Weighted mean returns empty raster
I can't figure out why this returns an error yet these are the values I need to work with.
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.78
r1 <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=6, vals=0.00:0.56)
r2 <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=6, vals=0.00000000:0.03338733)
r3 <- weighted.mean(r1, r2, na.rm=TRUE)


Have you tried evaluating 0.00:0.56 & 0.00000000:0.03338733 ?

@margusl not sure what you mean

Colon operator takes only integer values, execute 0.00:0.56 and 0.00000000:0.03338733  and you'll see they both return 0, i.e. both of your rasters are filled with zeroes.

Perhaps instead of 0.00:0.56 you are looking for vals = seq(0, 0.56, length.out = 600)

Since all your weights are zero, weighted means cannot be computed. With more sensible weights this appears to work:
library(terra)
set.seed(1)
r1 <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=6, vals=sample(10, 600, replace=TRUE))
r2 <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=6, vals=sample(10, 600, replace=TRUE))
r3 <- weighted.mean(r1, r2, na.rm=TRUE)
r3
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :      sum 
#min value   : 2.214286 
#max value   : 8.481481 

